# python add package into pip

Tags: python, installation, package, pip

I'm trying to add my package into to the python package index.

I registered the package into the Python Package Index.

Added a MANIFEST.in in my repo:

```
include README.rst
include MANIFEST.in
include CHANGELOG.rst
include LICENSE
include requirements.txt
include requirements-test.txt
include setup.py
recursive-include mypackagename *
```

and a setup.py file:

```
import os
from setuptools import setup

install_requires = ["requests"]

base_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

setup(
    name = "mypackagename",
    version = "0.0.5.dev",
    description = "My Description",
    long_description="\n\n".join([
        open(os.path.join(base_dir, "README.rst"), "r").read(),
        open(os.path.join(base_dir, "CHANGELOG.rst"), "r").read()
    ]),
    url = "https://github.com/myaccount/mypackagename",
    author = "My Name",
    author_email = "my@email.com",
    packages = ["mypackagename"],
    zip_safe = False,
    install_requires = install_requires,
    test_suite = "tests.get_tests",
)
```

but when i do: pip install mypackagename

this error is shown:

> Downloading/unpacking mypackagename   Could not find any downloads
>
> that satisfy the requirement mypackagename Cleaning up... No
>
> distributions at all found for mypackagename

Comment: Can you confirm your package made it on the python index?

Comment: it's in the python index, but i need to do like something setup.py update or something? the files are auto fetched from my repo? o i need upload my package files to python index?

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure PIP looks at github...